# Bellman Ford to detect negative cycles with exactly $k\leq n-1$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph with arc weights $c\colon E\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and let $k\in\mathbb N$. Describe how the algorithm of Bellman-Ford can be adjusted to detect whether $G$ contains a negative cycle with exactly $k\leq |V|-1$ edges. Hint: You can use the algorithm of BellmanFord(r,l) that terminates after the first $l$ iterations of BellmanFord(r) and returns the distances $r-u$ for all $u\in V$ and parents up to this point.
Do you have a idea how solve this task? I have now idea but I think I have to use the parents of $u$ after $l$ iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to use original Bellman—Ford algorithm rather than its further optimizations or retellings. An important property of the original approach is that during each series of relaxations along all edges they do not “update” the existing array of distance bounds to other vertices, but create a new array of improved bounds. (Think, why it is important! What is the meaning of each such bound? When does it equal to the distance?) Secondly, you may modify the graph.

Few more questions you may need to ask yourself. How to determine existence of any negative cycle using Bellman—Ford algorithm? Why is this criterium correct?